# Sort Stack Exchange answers by votes

Tags: discussion, google-chrome

On Stack Exchange sites, "accepted" answers are often on top, but I usually want the highest-voted answer. How can I program Chrome to sort answers by votes?

Comment: Hmm. I did say maybe... if this is a programming question please may you add an minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Why is this Javascript question moved to Meta and retagged?

Comment: @andi Perhaps you weren't clear about what the Question was really about? Were you looking for a user script to do this?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the behavior of my browser on Stack Exchange sites by using Javascript.

Comment: I imagine you've already checked that none such exist on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com)?

Comment: While I don't agree with what I am about to say, note that if you don't show that you've made an attempt, your question will be closed and downvoted into oblivion. Also, the dupe is complete garbage in my opinion, as it's clear what the OP is asking is completely different. My suggestion would be to disregard the accepted answer and sort the answers by votes using the standard method.

Comment: Yeah, that dupe target is completely wrong. The duplicate is a feature request to make it the default behavior, this one is asking how to circumvent it client-side.

Comment: A workaround I found for this (given that my standard method of procrastinating is finding a random stack exchange and looking at top of all time): put a single asterisk into the search box and click search. One of the sorting options for results is 'Votes'. Voilah.

Comment: @andi - because when you ask about how Stack Exchange sites work or how to work around the limitations of the software that powers them, your question belongs on a respective Meta (MSO in this case). That said, I agree with those who pointed the question is not a duplicate, but it took me several reads to figure it out - a highlight on "program", perhaps, would've helped. I voted to reopen, should be open now

Comment: When I select "votes" on one question.... subsequent questions I visit retain that preferred sort order

Comment: maybe test https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18392/firefox-extension-userscript-to-prevent-accepted-answer-from-sticking-to-top-on

Comment: I don't think this should've been migrated to begin with, but I do think we can help. There are userscripts out there that do this or include this functionality.

Comment: @zcoop98 - why wouldn't it? For the main site, it does not meet the guidelines as it is a too broad request (besides, it is already established they do not want to "program Chrome", just to be able to sort differently). Even if it was, it would be downvoted sure as hell for lack of research. Here they are likely to get good advice (where else to find people who know about userscripts and such if not Meta?)

Comment: @Oleg Eh, maybe you're right. If they find help here it will be a net gain. Certainly no harm done regardless.

Comment: @zcoop98 now that note of yours got me thinking: the question is migrated from SO proper, and one needs 5 rep on main to participate on Meta. The OP currently has only 1 rep on main, but is able to comment here most likely because of the "can comment on own posts" rule, how curious.